# How to destructure a Pair object into two variables in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, tuples

I have a function that returns `Pair`:

```kotlin
fun createTuple(a: Int, b: Int): Pair<Int, Int> {
    return Pair(a, b)
}
```

I want to initialize variables `a` and `b` using this function and then reassign them inside loop:

```kotlin
var (a, b) = createTuple(0, 0)
for (i in 1..10) {
    createTuple(i, -i).let{
       a = it.first
       b = it.second
    }
    println("a=$a; b=$b")
}
```

Using `let` seems awkward. Is there a better way to unwrap `Pair` inside loop?

The following lines do not compile:

```kotlin
(a, b) = createTuple(i, -i)
a, b = createTuple(i, -i)
```

Comment: Destructuring assignment is not supported. There's an open issue for it on the tracker that's a few years old. If you use `run` instead of `let`, you can drop the `it`s.

Comment: Your question is very unclear on what you want to achieve. Here, you could just do `for (i in 1..10) { a = i; b = -i }`

Comment: @SiddharthSharma it is a minimal example. My question was about destructuring assignment and Tenfour04 answered it

Comment: @Sergey Haha okay, then your question could have been a lot more minimal. For example, "How to destructure a `Pair` object into two existing variables"

Answer (score 7):

`var (a, b) = createPair(0, 0)` compiles fine for me.

Your problem probably is using `createTuple(i, -i)` instead of `createPair(i, -i)`.

Comment: Sorry, it was a copy/paste error. My answer was about destructuring assignment, see Tenfour04 comment